# While generating build react giving us TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of null

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to build my react project but it's saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of null

on

> C:\Users\Modi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\config\paths.js:23
> const hasSlash = inputPath.endsWith('/');
> My webpack file is like

```
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  externals: {
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
      apiUrl: "/api",
    }),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could try to use [this](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/issues/1247#issuecomment-454644352) workaround.

Basically, try to modify `module.export` like this:

```
module.exports = {
...
webpackConfig: require('react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js'),
    dangerouslyUpdateWebpackConfig(webpackConfig, env) {
        webpackConfig.output = {
            ...webpackConfig.output,
            publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_URL || ''
        };
        return webpackConfig;
    },
...
}
```

Comment: This problem is occurring in windows not in linux.

Comment: In module.export you posted